# pdf file rendered in portrait instead of landscape

Tags: css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pdf-generation, princely

We are using princely gem to generate pdf documents on our `rails 4` app.  For the last couple of days, the generated pdf is rendering in portrait mode instead of the specified landscape mode; this functionality has been working fine for years.

There have been some updates being done on the ruby/rails versions on the server, but nothing has been changed on the pdf generation code itself.

One interesting aspect is that the pdf is generated in landscape mode on the development server, when I test it locally on my machine(Mac). The same code generates pdf in portrait mode on the staging/production server (Linux).

Related code:

**From Gemfile**

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
gem 'princely', git: "git@github.com:mbleigh/princely.git"
....
```

**Pdf render code:**

```
render :pdf => "ticket",
       :template => "admin/tickets/print.pdf.erb",
       :stylesheets => ["printpdf.css"]
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/printpdf.css:**

```
@page {                                                                            
  size: 8.5in 11in landscape;                                                      
  margin: 5mm 5mm 5mm 5mm;                                                         
}                                                                                  
@page {                                                                            
  @bottom-right {                                                                  
    content: counter(page);                                                        
  }                                                                                
}                                                                                  
#pagebreak {                                                                       
  page-break-after: always;                                                        
}
```

**Princely command executed (as shown in the log):**

```
PRINCE XML PDF COMMAND
/usr/local/bin/prince --input=html --server --log=/Users/prakash/Projects/main_project/log/prince.log  -s /Users/prakash/Projects/main_project/app/assets/stylesheets/printpdf.css  --silent - -o -
```

Rails version was changed from `4.2.4` to `4.2.5.1` recently, and ruby version was changed from `2.2.0` to `2.3.0`. I rolled back both these changes on the staging server, but reverting neither of those changes fixes the portrait-instead-of-landscape issue.

Would appreciate any suggestions on where to look for the root cause of this problem, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Final Solution**

This was fixed by downgrading `sprockets-rails` gem from `3.0.0` to `2.3.3` because of [this issue](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/237).

**How I got there**

Found an error message in `prince.log` file generated by the `princexml` command line utility which said `printpdf.css: warning: can't open input file: No such file or directory`

That made me realize that the `princexml` commandline utility was being passed `printpdf.css` as the value for the css file, instead of the fully-qualified path: `/Users/prakash/Projects/main_project/app/assets/stylesheets/printpdf.css` on staging.

Debugging through [princely code](https://github.com/mbleigh/princely/blob/7526cbefb632b19427b0f9f80428fe1717b18087/lib/princely/asset_support.rb#L19), found that `Rails.application.assets` is being returned as nil here.

One other interesting thing I noticed during this exercise:

Downgrading rails version from `4.2.5.1` to `4.2.4` originally to rollback all my changes did not downgrade the version of `sprockets-rails` gem to `2.3.3`; it still kept it at `3.0.0`; hence my conclusion that the rails upgrade step was not a culprit for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get this right with princely take a look at [combine_pdf](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf), here a sample that rotates a pdf file and saves it into another file.

```
require "combine_pdf"

pdf = CombinePDF.load("file.pdf")
pdf.pages.each {|p| p.orientation :landscape }
pdf.save 'my.pdf'
```